# How to separate the string into two categories in jstl?

Tags: javascript

i have a string as,
String value = "Bhavani<>12<<>>Pallavi<>13<<>>Charanya<>14";

Now i need split the names and those values.
I am unable to identify what to do.

I need to print the values as

```
Output
---

-----------------------------
' Name       '  value       ' 
'------------'--------------'
' Bhavani    '  12          '
' Pallavi    '  13          '
' Charanya   '  14          '
'            '              '
----------------------------'
```

I think it can be done in jstl level..
But can anyone help me how to split that string.

Answer (score 2):

you can use str.replace to create an object:

```js
strvalue = "Bhavani<>12<<>>Pallavi<>13<<>>Charanya<>14"
 
obj={};

strvalue.replace(/(\w+)<>(\w+)/g,function(_,m1,m2){
  obj[m1]=m2
})
 
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: How to do the same in jstl

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var str = 'Bhavani<>12<<>>Pallavi<>13<<>>Charanya<>14';
str = str.split('<<>>')
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  str[i] = str[i].split('<>');
}
alert(str.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

first split with <<>>
than  split wiht <>
so you will get array with Bhavani , 12 in two indexes.
its simple to show in any way on view.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd store the key-value pairs in an object:

```
var myObj = {};
var string = 'Bhavani<>12<<>>Pallavi<>13<<>>Charanya<>14';
var stringArray = string.split('<<>>');

for(i in stringArray){
    var key = stringArray[i].split('<>')[0];
    var value = stringArray[i].split('<>')[1];
    myObj[key] = value;
}

console.log('My object looks like', myObj);
```

Comment: Yea , thats right when i use javascript.But i am unable to handle the same in jstl

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, you'll get an array of objects with a name and value inside each object:

```js
let value = "Bhavani<>12<<>>Pallavi<>13<<>>Charanya<>14";
let splittedString = value.split("<<>>");
let names = [];

splittedString.forEach(function(value) {
  let splittedProps = value.split("<>");
  names.push({
    name: splittedProps[0],
    value: splittedProps[1]
  });
});

console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str =  "Bhavani<>12<<>>Pallavi<>13<<>>Charanya<>14";
var strArr = str.split("<<>>");
var result = {};
for(var i in strArr){
    var p = strArr[i].split("<>");
    result[p[0]] = p[1];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First split with <<>>
then split string with <>

var string = 'Bhavani<>12<<>>Pallavi<>13<<>>Charanya<>14';

string = string.split('<<>>');

for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

string[i] = string[i].split('<>');

}`

```js
var string = 'Bhavani<>12<<>>Pallavi<>13<<>>Charanya<>14';

string = string.split('<<>>');

for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

  string[i] = string[i].split('<>');

}

alert(string.join("\n"));
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "Bhavani<>12<<>>Pallavi<>13<<>>Charanya<>14";
var txt = str.split("<<>>").join("|").split("<>").join("|").split("|")
var object=[];
for (var i=0; i<txt.length;i=i+2){
 object.push({Name:txt[i],Value:txt[i+1]}); 
}
console.log(object);
```